# Redux thunk, difference between using it as a list or as an object

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, redux-thunk

I'm reading a code of a react project I found on GitHub and I found a different use of redux thunk, by seeing the official documentation at GitHub they use it this way:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers/index';

// Note: this API requires redux@>=3.1.0
const store = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  applyMiddleware(thunk)
);
```

but in the code I found the guy used:

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import { autoRehydrate, persistStore } from 'redux-persist'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from '../reducers';

const middleWare = [thunk];

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(...middleWare)(createStore);

export default configureStore = (onComplete) => {
  const store = autoRehydrate()(createStoreWithMiddleware)(reducers);
  persistStore(store, { storage: AsyncStorage }, onComplete);

  return store;
};
```

what is the difference between using it as a list or as an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the function signature ([source](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/src/applyMiddleware.js#L19)):

```
function applyMiddleware(...middlewares) { /* logic */ }
```

`applyMiddleware` uses the [rest parameter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) which allows representing an indefinite number of arguments **as an array**.

Because of this, both

```
applyMiddleware(thunk, otherMiddleware);
```

and

```
const middlewares = [thunk, otherMiddleware];
applyMiddleware(...middlewares);
```

are equally valid.